# Is there any solution to correct my source code in my project?

Tags: android

I got error while running, while it shows cannot resolve symbol

I was to trying go to the next activity while clicking on the button "welcome", but unfortunately it shows error, it does not go that the specific page, got error in this code
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserDetailsActivity.class);

Comment: share your code with us.

Comment: When asking a question, you should try to think about what information others will need to answer it. For example, we have no idea what your "welcome" button is, nor what the rest of your code looks like. This makes it very hard to help you, except to give a very generic answer of "UserDetailsActivity doesn't appear to exist", which is essentially the same thing that your error message already told you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.